# EF Core lazy loading proxies return null randomly instead of entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .Net Core 3.1 application with an SQL database. I use lazy-loading proxies to automatically  retrieve data from related tables. Basically, I have a table, which references some other entities via 1-to-many or 1-to-1 relation. Thing is, most of the cases, every relation is OK, every entity is loaded and I can read it's properties (name field, for example).

But, in very specific cases, those entities **won't load**, although relation Id is there. It looks like this:

Model is like this:

```
public partial class Delegation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int UserFrom { get; set; }
    public int UserTo { get; set; }

    public virtual User UserFromNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual User UserToNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

Initialization inside database context:

```
public virtual DbSet<Delegation> Delegations { get; set; }
...
modelBuilder.Entity<Delegation>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

    entity.HasOne(d => d.UserFromNavigation)
        .WithMany(p => p.DelegationsUserFromNavigation)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserFrom)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Delegations_Users_From");

     entity.HasOne(d => d.UserToNavigation)
        .WithMany(p => p.DelegationsUserToNavigation)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserTo)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Delegations_Users_To");
});
```

This specific example is only one of the many, there are also not loading virtual ICollections of other entities in other models.

Here, on debug screenshot, UserTo is OK, but UserFrom is NULL.

[image: UserTo is OK, but UserFrom is NULL]

Manually searching for the entity by Id and retrieving it's properties is working, but it makes code much dirtier.

Is there any way to force EF to load those missing entities or am I doing a mistake here? This behavior looks really random.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I am experiencing the same issues.

Comment: @MortenMoulder, yes and no. There is a workaround, however, but this is still a bug and EF Core team will try to fix this. The solution is to create proxy explicitly (dbContext.CreateProxy<Model>()). Here is a thread on github: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20118

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that lazy loading is enabled for your DbContext. In Entity Framework Core, lazy loading is not enabled by default, and you need to explicitly enable it Startup file or OnConfiguring method.

```
optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
```

Or instead of relying on lazy loading, you can use the Include method to explicitly load the navigation properties when querying the data:

```
var data = rmscontext.Delegations
               .Include(d => d.UserFromNavigation)
               .Include(d => d.UserToNavigation)
               .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == id);
```