# Create one lazy and one eager DbContext via inheritance?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am using EFCore 3.1.5 and I have a DbContext I want to be able to use in the same controller or service either lazy or eager. However, it seems like I cannot get it to load lazy properly. Eager seems to work fine.

Whenever I do something as simple as:

```
var users = await _lazyDbContext
    .Users
    .Take(10)
    .ToListAsync();
```

each navigational property on each `User` is null. However, with eager loading, it works fine:

```
var users = await _dbContext
    .Users
    .Include(x => x.Contact)
    .Take(10)
    .ToListAsync();
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<LazyUserContext>((sp, opt) =>
        {
            var connectionString = "very secret";
            opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.CommandTimeout(300));
            opt.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
        });

    services.AddDbContext<UserContext>((sp, opt) =>
        {
            var connectionString = "very secret";
            opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.CommandTimeout(300));
        });

    services.AddScoped<IUserContext, UserContext>();
    services.AddScoped<ILazyUserContext, LazyUserContext>();
}
```

**UserContext.cs**

```
public interface IUserContext
{
    DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class UserContext : DbContext, IUserContext
{
    public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options) : base(options) {}

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>(e => 
        {
            e.HasOne(x => x.Contact).WithOne(x => x.User).HasForeignKey(x => x.ContactId);
        }
    }
}
```

**LazyUserContext.cs**

```
public interface ILazyUserContext : IContext {}

public class LazyUserContext : UserContext, ILazyUserContext
{
    public LazyUserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options) : base(options) {}
}
```

What could the issue be here? I have tried to IoC both the interface and the class in my controller/service. I have tried with and without the `services.AddScoped<>()`.

All I want is be able to use a lazy dbContext or eager dbContext, where I want to default to the eager one.

Comment: this may sound stupid but try switch these around `opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.CommandTimeout(300));
            opt.UseLazyLoadingProxies();` so `opt.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.CommandTimeout(300));`

Comment: @Seabizkit Unfortunately that won't make a difference. I know the lazy loading works, because if I simply remove all the `LazyContext` stuff so there is only 1 DbContext, the lazy loading works perfectly.

Comment: ok mmm im thinking its how u register it aka.... u need to reuse the defined way by getting it instance `services.AddScoped<DbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<ParadoxCoreContext>());` this is from my own project but tweek to ur needs... try that

Comment: This page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.proxiesextensions.uselazyloadingproxies?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ProxiesExtensions_UseLazyLoadingProxies_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptionsBuilder_System_Boolean_ mentions about possibly having to call `services.AddEntityFrameworkProxies()`

Comment: @Seabizkit Your `DbContext` is that the actual `DbContext` Entity Framework class or my LazyUserContext? Because nope, that won't work.

Comment: @Neil Nope, navigational properties are still null. I've added `services.AddEntityFrameworkProxies()` before both my `services.AddDbContext()` and I've tried adding it after.

Comment: @MortenMoulder this is what i meant `services.AddScoped<ILazyUserContext, LazyUserContext>((provider =>   
    provider.GetService<LazyUserContext>()
);` you need to tell the register in ur scoped version to use the already defined construction, where you have specified UseLazyLoadingProxies, well that is my understadning otherwise how would `services.AddScoped<ILazyUserContext, LazyUserContext>();` know how to construct LazyUserContext...

Comment: @Seabizkit Ah yes, that makes sense

Comment: @MortenMoulder pleasure sozs i wasn't more clear the first time... you just looked so on the ball, i thought u might get what i was hinting at.

Answer (score 2):

### The solution

> All I want is be able to use a lazy dbContext or eager dbContext

You should be able to just set the configuration in the subclasses:

```
public class LazyContext : MyContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    }
}

public class EagerContext : MyContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

There are two options of setting db option configuration, via the the constructor (and thus the DI route), or via the class itself. Since this particular setting is class-specific and you don't want to juggle it in the DI registration, it makes sense to rely on the class-specific configuration method.

---

### Why your solution didn't work

The reason your initial approach didn't work is because `AddDbContext<T>` registers *that specific `T`* as your dependency type. From the source:

> The AddDbContext extension method registers DbContext types with a scoped lifetime by default.

Note that it registers the context type, not any interfaces/ancestors of that context type.

So when you do this:

```
services.AddDbContext<LazyUserContext>((sp, opt) =>
{
    var connectionString = "very secret";
    opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.CommandTimeout(300));
    opt.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
});

services.AddScoped<ILazyUserContext, LazyUserContext>();
```

If your class has a dependency of type `ILazyUserContext`, it only listens to the second registration and flatout ignores the first one.

Only when your class has a dependency of `LazyUserContext` will you actually get the db context options you specified in the first registration.

---

Note that you can use this type-specific registration behavior to your advantage when you want to register a default implementation:

```
// Specific interface => specific type
services.AddScoped<IUserContext, UserContext>();
services.AddScoped<ILazyUserContext, LazyUserContext>();

// General interface => explicitly chosen default type
services.AddScoped<IContext, UserContext>();
```

This allows you to have some classes that demand to specifically have the eager/lazy loading, and other classes which just take in whatever is the default (which could change over time).

Comment: `this.Configuration` is not a property on my class. Are you sure that one exists in EFCore 3.1.5? Also, it seems like you have a copy/paste error in your first section. 2x LazyContext and 2x Enabled = true

Comment: this is basically reinforcing my comment on the question i made, and should be a way to get it to work without doing this... altho nothing wrong with this.

Comment: @MortenMoulder: You're right I copied the wrong snippet. I updated the snippet to EF Core, though the gist of the answer remains largely unchanged.

Comment: @Flater Instead of having an `EagerContext`, couldn't I just use the `MyContext` from your example?

Comment: @MortenMoulder: Yep, assuming this is the only difference between them. Though for clarity, I'd generally advise having two explicitly descriptive class names instead of just one being labeled as lazy and the other not being labeled as eager.

Comment: @MortenMoulder: Note that if you keep both `EagerContext` and `MyContext` around, you can apply what I discussed in the third section of the answer, where `MyContext` can return _either_ context (as a freely choosable default option) whereas `EagerContext` **always** returns the eager one. I used interfaces in that example but it works the same for base types.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Flater. I've been trying to get this to work for too many hours now, and both me, my team, and someone on SO thinks this is a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60453551/ef-core-lazy-loading-proxies-return-null-randomly-instead-of-entities

I basically run into an issue where the property is null. I'll issue a bug report with EFCore team on GitHub. Maybe they know what's up

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the fact that both context constructors use (depend on) one and the same options type - `DbContextOptions<UserContext>`.

`AddDbContext<TContext>` actually registers two types - the context itself `TContext` as well as factory for the context options dependency `DbContextOptions<TContext>`.

So you are registering two options factories (along with configuration action) - `DbContextOptions<UserContext>` and `DbContextOptions<LazyUserContext>`. However, as mentioned at the beginning `LazyUserContext` depends on `DbContextOptions<UserContext>`, so it's simply instantiated with the first options set-up, i.e. exactly like the other.

This is not specific for lazy loading, but for any scenario which requires different options (different database type/connection string etc.) and is the reason generic class `DbContextOptions<TContext>` exists.

The solution is to change the `LazyUserContext` dependency

```
public LazyUserContext(DbContextOptions<LazyUserContext> options) : base(options) { }
```

and since this won't compile because the base expects `DbContextOptions<UserContext>`, add second protected constructor to the base class accepting just `DbContextOptions`

```
protected UserContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
```